# Getting an Invalid Cursor state error in the forge process of an Endeca baseline

Tags: endeca

Error in the forge log is `Unable to determine the number of columns in the ODBC result: [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Invalid cursor state`

Endeca is a bit black-box, so I'm not sure exactly what sql call is causing this error

Comment: So it turns out we changed a sql stored proc & I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glenn,

In SQLServer 2005 (and perhaps other SQLServer versions), calls to ODBC `SQLNumResultCols` have been known to return invalid column counts or throw errors when the query is a call to a non-trivial stored procedure.  If your query calls a stored procedure, see if you derive the same outcome using direct table or view reads, perhaps combined with logic in Forge.

Brett